# Removing white noise and static from streamed audio file in python

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, sox, pydub

I'm consuming a live audio stream from a websdr via a websocket by running a generator function which grabs chunks of the audio stream and saves those chunks into a wav file. The problem is that the generated audio file contains a ton of noise (static + white noise). I'm not an expert in audio processing, however i've used both [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub) and [sox](https://github.com/rabitt/pysox) in an attempt to remove the aforementioned noise, but nothing has worked so far. Sox is quite radical at removing the "noise" it gets from the profile file, to the point that it dramatically distorts audio quality. Are there any other potential methods of static + white noise removal from files that i've missed? Or perhaps there is something wrong with my implementation?

Below are relevant snippets of code

1. Generate raw audio header

   ```py
   def audio_header(data, sample_rate, bits_per_sample, channels):
       datasize = len(data) * channels * bits_per_sample // 8
       o = bytes("RIFF", "ascii")  # (4byte) Marks file as RIFF
       o += (datasize + 36).to_bytes(4, "little")  # (4byte) File 
       size in bytes excluding
       # this and RIFF marker
       o += bytes("WAVE", "ascii")  # (4byte) File type
       o += bytes("fmt ", "ascii")  # (4byte) Format Chunk Marker
       o += (16).to_bytes(4, "little")  # (4byte) Length of above 
         format data
       o += (1).to_bytes(2, "little")  # (2byte) Format type (1 - PCM)
       o += channels.to_bytes(2, "little")  # (2byte)
       o += sample_rate.to_bytes(4, "little")  # (4byte)
       o += (sample_rate * channels * bits_per_sample // 
         8).to_bytes(
             4, "little"
          )  # (4byte)
       o += (channels * bits_per_sample // 8).to_bytes(
       2, "little"
       )  # (2byte) bytes per sample
       o += bits_per_sample.to_bytes(2, "little")  # (2byte) bits per sample
       o += bytes("data", "ascii")  # (4byte) Data Chunk Marker
       o += datasize.to_bytes(4, "little")  # (4byte) Data size in bytes
       return o
   ```
2. Generator function grabbing audio data from stream

   ```
   class GeneratorClass:


   def __init__(self, url):

    self.bytes_count = 0
    self.chunk_size = 180000
    self.frames = []
    self.is_done = False
    self.ws = create_connection(url)

   def stream_function(self):

    while True:

        try:
            result = self.ws.recv()
        except Exception as e:
            self.ws.close()
            yield ""
            raise RuntimeError(f"Request failed: {self.request_url}, error: {e}")

        self.frames.append(result)

        self.bytes_count += len(result)

        if self.bytes_count >= self.chunk_size:
            self.bytes_count = 0
            self.is_done = True
        else:
            self.is_done = False

        if self.is_done is True:
            yield b"".join(self.frames)
            self.frames.clear()
   ```
3. Getting audio data and processing using pydbub

   ```
    # example url

     stream_url = 'wss://eshail.batc.org.uk/~~stream?v=11?f=10489690&band=0&lo=0.35&hi=2.95&mode=0&name=a?squelch=1?autonotch=1'

     stream_func = GeneratorClass(stream_url)
     generator = stream_func.stream_function()

     while True:
       chunk = next(generator)

       # save raw data to file along with header
       with open(raw_file, "wb") as segment_file:
          segment_file.write(
                  audio_header(
                      data=chunk,
                      sample_rate=7100,
                      bits_per_sample=8,
                      channels=1)
                 + chunk)
   ```
4. Applying high pass filter (not sure if this really changes anything since, because of the white noise and static the audio file in its entirety is noisy)

   ```
     file = AudioSegment.from_file(audio_file.wav, format='wav')

     print(file.dBFS) # this gives me 43.38

     import pydub.scipy_effects

     filtered = file.high_pass_filter(1, order=2)

     filtered.export('filtered_file.wav', format='wav')
   ```
5. Using pysox to remove noise from the file

   ```
     # generate silence file



     # get silence
     s = AudioSegment.from_file('filtered_file.wav', format='wav')

     ms = 0
     current_silence = 0
     longest_time = 500
     longest_val = None
     for i in s:
        if i.dBFS < -10.0:
           length = ms - current_silence
           if length > longest_time:
               longest_val = s[current_silence : ms]
               longest_time = length
           current_silence = ms + 1
        ms += 1
     print(longest_val)
     longest_val.export('silence_file.wav', format='wav')


   # remove silence

    import sox 

    tfm = sox.Transformer()
    tfm.compand()
    tfm.norm(4.0)

    tfm.noiseprof('silence.wav', 'profile.test')

    tfm.noisered(profile_path='profile.test', amount=0.2)


    array_out = tfm.build_array(input_filepath='filtered_file.wav', sample_rate_in=7100)
    tfm.build_file(input_array=array_out, sample_rate_in=7100, 
                   output_filepath='cleaned.wav')
   ```

Comment: As I understand it, the problem with noise is that it's random -- so trying to remove it from an audio file is a lot like trying to remove pee from the pool (or if you prefer, trying to correct the roundoff error of a floating-point math operation without knowing what the operation was).  That is, it can only really be done effectively if the computer somehow knows what the original audio was "meant to" sound like; otherwise you start removing the signal as much as the noise.  If your audio files are all quite similar, you might be able train up a neural network to do it.

Comment: Yeah that was my concern - makes sense though!